# Systemd After not starting service

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04

`letsencrypt.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Renews letsencrypt certificates
After=network.target letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/etc/letsencrypt/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/letsencrypt renew
```

When I start this service manually: `sudo systemctl start letsencrypt` it doesn't seem to start the `letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service` service. I've ran `sudo systemctl start letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service` and it works as it should.

What I'm trying to do is that when `letsencrypt.service` is finished I'd like it to start the `letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service` service.

Comment: First of all you have the usage of `After=` backwards. Your code show that `letsencrypt.service` should be started *After* the `letstncrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service`. The [answer below](https://serverfault.com/questions/836451/systemd-after-not-starting-service/836584#836584) by [@Mark Stosberg](https://serverfault.com/users/63268/mark-stosberg) shows how to do what you want. If you wanted it to work based on dependencies you would have to `start` the `letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service` service and have the `Requires=` listed in its `.service` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`After=` does not imply a dependency relationship (only order), you can establish dependency with `Requires=` or `Wants=` directive.

> **Requires=**
>   Configures requirement dependencies on other units. If this unit gets activated, the units listed here will be activated as
>   well. If one of the other units gets deactivated or its activation
>   fails, this unit will be deactivated. This option may be specified
>   more than once or multiple space-separated units may be specified in
>   one option in which case requirement dependencies for all listed names
>   will be created. Note that requirement dependencies do not influence
>   the order in which services are started or stopped. This has to be
>   configured independently with the `After=` or `Before=` options. If a unit
>   `foo.service` requires a unit bar.service as configured with Requires=
>   and no ordering is configured with `After=` or `Before=`, then both units
>   will be started simultaneously and without any delay between them if
>   `foo.service` is activated. Often, it is a better choice to use `Wants=`
>   instead of `Requires=` in order to achieve a system that is more robust
>   when dealing with failing services.
>
> Note that this dependency type does not imply that the other unit
>   always has to be in active state when this unit is running.
>   Specifically: failing condition checks (such as `ConditionPathExists=`,
>   `ConditionPathExists=`, … — see below) do not cause the start job of a
>   unit with a `Requires=` dependency on it to fail. Also, some unit types
>   may deactivate on their own (for example, a service process may decide
>   to exit cleanly, or a device may be unplugged by the user), which is
>   not propagated to units having a `Requires=` dependency. Use the
>   `BindsTo=` dependency type together with `After=` to ensure that a unit
>   may never be in active state without a specific other unit also in
>   active state (see below).
>
> Note that dependencies of this type may also be configured outside of
>   the unit configuration file by adding a symlink to a `.requires/`
>   directory accompanying the unit file. For details, see above.
>
> **Wants=**
>   A weaker version of `Requires=`. Units listed in this option will be started if the configuring unit is. However, if the listed
>   units fail to start or cannot be added to the transaction, this has no
>   impact on the validity of the transaction as a whole. This is the
>   recommended way to hook start-up of one unit to the start-up of
>   another unit.
>
> Note that dependencies of this type may also be configured outside of
>   the unit configuration file by adding symlinks to a `.wants/` directory
>   accompanying the unit file. For details, see above.

Ref: http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is that when letsencrypt.service is finished I'd like it to start the letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service service.

You want to add this to your `letsencrypt.service` file then:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl start letsencrypt_concat_fullchain_privkey.service
```

This command will then be run serially after the command you gave in `ExecStart=`.

You can read more about `ExecStartPost=` in `man systemd.service` or look up any `systemd` directive in `man systemd.directives`.